# Missing class org.hibernate.ejb.hibernatePersistence in a maven web project

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

I am building a maven web project ( jsf+ejb3+jpa2) named " tuto.maven" using eclipse kepler, glassfish4.0, postgresSql 9.1, but where I try to run the project on a server a problem occurs
"cannot Deploy tuto.maven
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence "

Here is the persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/postgres</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.model.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tuto</groupId>
  <artifactId>tuto.maven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1B</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>

</project>
```

any idea please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem of version, I use the latest version and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the jar's and search for prg.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence class in your jars.

You also need to add in your persistence unit. Mention the name of the domain class.

```
<class>yourpackage.class</class>
```

Comment: I already have the jar containing the classe org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence under libraries/maven dependencies but it doesn't work, it's like glassfish can't recognise the jar